# How to prevent other compnents re-rendering when only single state changed in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, render

I created a react project using redux as state management. I have two different states stored in the same reducer and used by two different components. But every time I change the state in one component, the other component also re-rendered. How to prevent this rendering behavior?

You can try my sandbox here: https://pjm8e.csb.app/

I put some `console.log` inside each component, and both are rendered when the button clicked

Comment: You're mapping the whole state to props.  Map the subset you want for each component.  If those subsets don't overlap, they shouldn't rerender when that subset is invariant.

Comment: Can you share the link to your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening, because both of the components are connected to the whole state. So if you update only a small part of the state, it causes them both to rerender. You can use hooks for dispatch and selectors to only connect to relevant parts of the store. Here is a sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-architecture-1n0g7?file=/src/Consumer2.js

Comment: It works! So it's not necessary to use connect() from redux?

Comment: You can use either ```connect``` or hooks. Since everyone is now using hooks, I would recommend this approach. 
If you would prefer connect, you can still have the same result, but you will have to map only a subset of the state in you ```mapStateToProps```